# How can I use case when as well as where in sql

Tags: sql, case, where-clause

This is my query but there is an error -

> 'INCORRECT SYNTAX NEAR WHERE'

how should i proceed

```
UPDATE UpdateChecker
Set UPDATED = Case   
WHEN Datediff(DAY, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, (SELECT TOP(1) ['Debt Market Data$'].Date From ['Debt Market Data$'] ORDER BY Date Desc)) = 0 
THEN 'YES'
ELSE 'NO'
WHERE  [TABLE NAME]='Debt Market Data$'
END
```

Comment: Post code as text, not as screenshots.

Comment: okay shall do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to put your where after the case when ... end clause.

```
update UpdateChecker
set updated = case when ... then 'YES' else 'NO' end
where ....
```